# Getting additional rows from power-shell Export-Excel command

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script below:

```
$DataVariable = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "B1" -Database "SQL4" -Query "SELECT * FROM Table1"

$DataVariable | Export-Excel  -Path $OutputFile -WorkSheetname "Robert" -Title "MG" -TitleFillPattern DarkDown
```

If I run this script, am getting additional rows, i.e. `RowError`, `Table`, `ItemArray`, `HasErrors`.

How can I get rid of these rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra fields are returned by invoke-sqlcmd , you can remove those by using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) :

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "snape\test" -Database test -Query $query | 
Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | 
Export-Excel  -Path "C:\Users\test\test.xlsx"  -Title "MG" -TitleFillPattern DarkDown
```

Answer (score 2):

> **tl;dr**
>
> I would say that your problem lies more with the Invoke-Sqlcmd command more than the Export-Excel command.
>
> - only select the columns that you are interested in before piping them
>   to `Export-Excel`.
> - or, select everything and use `-ExcludeProperty` to remove what you
>   do not want before piping to `Export-Excel`

I'm actually quite impressed that Export-Excel get's the values out of `System.Data.DataRow` type.

[image: Getting my members]

Throwing a modified version of your script into a variable and calling `Get-Member` on that shows us that the TypeName is `System.Data.DataRow`.

If we open up [the MSDN page on that type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties), we see it has the following properties (*highlighting is my own*)...

> **HasErrors**, Item()..., **ItemArray**, **RowError**, **RowState**, **Table**...

We can't see them using `Get-Member` but if we pipe our variable to `Select-Object -Property *` then we see those hidden guys!

[image: Selecting all]

I would say that your problem lies more with the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command more than the `Export-Excel` command.
The quick workaround for this is to only select the columns that you are interested in before piping them to `Export-Excel`. Or, as pointed out by @Abhijith pk, select everything and using `-ExcludeProperty` to remove what you do not want

```
$dataVar | 
  Select Col1 | 
  Export-excel `
    -Path .\testing\datavar.xlsx `
    -WorkSheetname Doug `
    -Title DougSoCool `
    -TitleFillPatten DarkDown
```

[image: He really is]

HTH

Comment: I used your method but am now getting an error: Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At C:\branches\Ops\PSScripts\TestingDSTest.ps1:478 char:24
+ ... taVariable |Select-Object [Test Code], LogNumber, Revisio

Comment: Try changing that `[Test Code]` to a 'Test Code'. Looks like you're mixing up SQL and PowerShell :)